# How to enlarge product images displayed through widget( product grid template)

Tags: product, product-list

I want to enlarge image size

[image: product]

I have inserted it through widget product grid template

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2?

If you mean oversized, better to do it in css/html if you want to enlarge your image.

Or if you want to display a bigger image because you use a small thumbnail size, have a look at your theme file *view.xml*

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html
and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_gallery.html